My start button on my 2d runner game wont work after i implemented difficulty selection
I'm making a simple 2d endless runner game for a project. The game is simple,

it has one infinitely repeating obstacle,
it is supposed to have 3 difficulty levels that the player can choose.
The score starts at 0
the score updates when a collision is detected above the obstacle
and ends the game when the player hits the obstacle.

(thanks to kikon for helping i modified your code a little)
I do have some other problems with my code I need to fix as well, but all help is appreciated so if any of you seeing this spot any other errors or questionable logic other than what I'm asking help for then please let me know.
Very sorry if it's just a small syntax error I missed. Here's the code:


const player = document.getElementById('player');
const obstacle = document.getElementById('obstacle');
const scoreValue = document.getElementById('score-value');
let score = 0;
let gameRunning = false;
let hasJumpedOver = false;

function updateScore() {
  score++;
  scoreValue.innerText = score;
}

function gameOver() {
  gameRunning = false;
  alert('Game Over! Your score is ' + score);
}

function moveObstacle() {
  if (!gameRunning) return;

  let obstaclePosition = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obstacle).getPropertyValue('right')) + speed;

  if (obstaclePosition < window.innerWidth) {
    obstacle.style.right = `${obstaclePosition + speed}px`;
  } else {
    obstacle.style.right = '0';
    hasJumpedOver = false; // Reset this flag when the obstacle resets
  }

  detectCollision();
}

function jump() {
  if (!player.classList.contains('jump')) {
    player.classList.add('jump');

    setTimeout(() => {
      player.classList.remove('jump');
    }, 500);
  }
}

function detectCollision() {
  let playerRect = player.getBoundingClientRect();
  let obstacleRect = obstacle.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (playerRect.left < obstacleRect.right &&
    playerRect.right > obstacleRect.left &&
    playerRect.top < obstacleRect.bottom &&
    playerRect.bottom > obstacleRect.top) {
    // Collision detected, end the game
    gameOver();
  } else if (playerRect.right < obstacleRect.left && !hasJumpedOver) {
    // Player has successfully jumped over the obstacle
    hasJumpedOver = true;
    updateScore();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    jump();
  }
});

setInterval(moveObstacle, 20);

const difficultyButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#difficulty-buttons button');

difficultyButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // remove selected class from all buttons
    difficultyButtons.forEach(btn => {
      btn.classList.remove('button-selected');
    });

    // add the selected class to clicked button
    this.classList.add('button-selected');
  });
});


// misc code for fade in and out on same page

document.getElementById('start-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('game-container').classList.add('visible');
  document.getElementById('main-page').classList.add('fade-out-up');
  gameRunning = true; // game starts when start button gets clicked
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main-page {
  z-index: 1;
}

#game-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: big;
  background-position: center center;
}


/*for game container fade in */

#game-container.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*stuff for main elements of the game*/

#player {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#obstacle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#score {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
}


/*for jump*/

.jump {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}


/*for the main page div to fade out*/

.fade-out-up {
  animation: fadeOutUp 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
}


/*for difficulty selectors */

.button-selected {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Endless Runner Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-page" class="w3-container">
    <h1 class="">Cube Runner 2D</h1>
    <p>Cube Runner 2D is an endless 2D runner game in where the object of the game is to get your score as high as possible before you run into the obstacle (you die).
    </p>
    <p>The game has <span style="font-weight: bold;">Three Difficulty levels </span>you can choose from below,
      <span class="w3-text-green" style="font-weight: bold;">Easy, </span>
      <span class="w3-text-yellow" style="font-weight: bold;">Medium, </span>and
      <span class="w3-text-red" style="font-weight: bold;">Hard.</span></p>


    <div id="difficulty-buttons">
      <button onclick="setDifficulty('easy')" class="w3-green">Easy</button>
      <button onclick="setDifficulty('medium')" class="w3-yellow">Medium</button>
      <button onclick="setDifficulty('hard')" class="w3-red">Hard</button>
    </div>

    <button id="start-button" class="w3-display-middle">Start Game</button>
  </div>

  <div id="game-container">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="obstacle"></div>
    <div id="score">Score: <span id="score-value">-1</span></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



